# [YAP 6.2.2][Prolog] "mmap" error during compilation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: prolog, mmap, ubuntu-20.04, yap

I have a problem with compiling YAP Prolog 6.2.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.
As usual, following the README, I browse into the YAP folder and give the command
`./configure` which is successful.
Next, I give the command `make` but it gives me this error:

```
%
%
% YAP OOOPS: mmap could not map at 0x10000000, got 0xffffffffffffffff.
%
%

   Exiting ....
make: *** [Makefile:534: startup.yss] Error 1
```

I have already installed the libraries suggested in the README file (gmp and readline), but I can't figure out what the problem is.
This same procedure works perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04LTS and Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today and decided to debug the problem. I found the cause of this problem and a hackish fix. Unfortunately the build fails later with a related problem that I have not managed to figure out.

The issue is that attempts to use `/dev/zero` to map executable memory using `mmap`. In Ubuntu 20.04 `/dev` is mounted with the `noexec` flag however. I patched the code to use anonymous memory instead, but as I said above it then just fails (by hanging) at a later point during the build. The hung process is attempting to allocate more memory repeatedly via `mmap`, but this is failing with `ENOMEM`.

If I find a proper solution I will upload a patch for all these issues somewhere and link it here.